# WPF | Send Info from Popup Child Window to Parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

i have this WPF application in which i am trying to make popup window. well window is created and working fine, but what i want to do. that if i press OK/Update button in that popup, The selected values should be passed the the parent window and that popup should be closed.

i have seen this problem solution here..

[C# - Return variable from child window to parent window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607925/c-sharp-return-variable-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-wpf)

But i do not understand how this delegates works..

I have done it like this..

When click on button this method will opens the popup window.

```
private void btnAddBeneficiaryPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AddBeneficiaryPopup addBen = new AddBeneficiaryPopup(refCustId);
        addBen.selectedBeneID += value => selectedBeneficiaryID = value;
        addBen.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { this.MyErrorMessage(ex); }
}
```

In Popup window in the constructor i have code like this.

```
public AddBeneficiaryPopup(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    refCustId = id;
    this.LoadReferenceBeneficiary();
}
```

Now this below Method i am working on and want to change it mostly..

```
private void cmbRefBene_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string beneId = null;
    if (cmbRefBene.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        try
        {
            beneId = ((DataRowView)cmbRefBene.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            selectedBeneID = beneId;
            bene.OpenConnection(str);

            SqlDataReader reader = bene.LookUpSingleBene(int.Parse(beneId));
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                tbName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                tbContactNo.Text = reader["ContactNo"].ToString();
                btnUpdate.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            reader.Close();
            bene.CloseConnnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyErrorMessage(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            bene.CloseConnnection();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in above code `selectedBeneID = beneId;` this beneId gives error. as i am trying to assign it selectedBeneID, as i think its a delegate to there must be another way to assigning values to it and passing it to the Parent Window..

But really am not sure how to work with this delegate and what to write to assign value to it.

i am getting error

`"cannot implicitly convert type string to "System.Action<string>"`

Comment: Create a common view model that is used by both the parent and the child window.

Comment: @Clemens
i have this window(.xaml) file through which new popup window(.xaml) file opens..
Not sure how common view model works.. New to WPF.

Comment: Search the web for MVVM, and read introductory articles about WPF Data Binding. Then set the DataContext property of the two windows to the same instance of your view model class. Thus they will be able to exchange data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution A** (getting your one working)

To get your solution running, change the following line in your `cmbRefBene_SelectionChanged` function:

```
selectedBeneID = beneId;
```

to

```
selectedBeneID(beneId);
```

Now you should not get the error message and the value should be set correctly.

---

---

---

**Solution B**

The following solution isn'n the most elegant but it always works:

Give your Popup Window a public Property (selectedBeneID).

```
public partial class AddBeneficiaryPopup : Window   {
    public string selectedBeneID;
.....
  }
}
```

Set this property in your `cmbRefBene_SelectionChanged` function.

---

MainWindow:

change `addBen.Show();` in your Main Window

to

`addBen.ShowDialog();
idreturned = addBen.selectedBeneID;`

---

Now The program will wait until you close the Popup.

After that you can access the property of your popup Window and read it out.

Comment: Thankyou sir..
What if i want two values? i mean id of beneficiary along with name of that beneficiary. is it possible with this??

Comment: I added Solution A, this should fix the error you described in the first place. To Add another value, just add another Action event, like with selectedBeneId and call it the same way. for example: 
    `public event Action<string> selectedBeneName;` and 
        `addBen.selectedBeneName += value => namereturned = value;`

Comment: yes sir, i already did have tested that and it worked but problem i did realized i need to get two values rather than one..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877458/wpf-delegate-get-two-values

So when i sent like this `selectedBeneID(beneId,reader["Name"].ToString());` i again got another issue for arguments..
However your Solution A works great as i already have tried it. Many Thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: sorry just saw your update.
Will try your answer of putting another action event..
Will let you know..
Thanks again.

Comment: Its Working Great. Thanks Sir. You are Awesome.. <3