# Save filters in advances settings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow in WPF. If I click on a button, this code is executed:

```
private void buttonAdvSett_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdvancedSettingsWindow advancedSettingsPopup = new AdvancedSettingsWindow();
    advancedSettingsPopup.ShowDialog();
}
```

A new window is opening. In this window I set some filters (via ComboBoxes). I want so save the strings from the ComboBoxes if I click on a costume "OK" button.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // save the strings from the comboboxes if I click OK and close the window
    this.Close();
}
```

I hope you can help me. 
Sorry for my bad English. English is not my native language.

Have a great day.

envy6

UPDATE:

This also worked for me:
In the AdvancedSettingsWindow:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Foo();
            this.Close();
        }

public event Action<string> Check;

public void Foo()
        {
            if(Check != null)
            {
                Check(methodINeedInMyMainWindow());
            }
        }
```

And in my MainWindow:

```
private void buttonAdvSett_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            AdvancedSettingsWindow advancedSettingsPopup = new AdvancedSettingsWindow();
            advancedSettingsPopup.Check += value => labelCurrentFilterText.Content = value;
            advancedSettingsPopup.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Source: [C# - Return variable from child window to parent window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607925/c-sharp-return-variable-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-wpf)

Comment: Why don't you expose these values as properties of the window? You can then access them after the window has been closed. You may also store if the window way closed via an "ok" button or "cancel" etc.

Comment: What do you mean with _save_? Do you want to save it to memory, so you can use it everywhere in your application, or do you want to save it to a file so you can load it when the application starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainWindow` button method should look like that:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AdvancedSettingsWindow newPopupWindow = new AdvancedSettingsWindow();
        newPopupWindow.ShowDialog();
        if(newPopupWindow.DialogResult == true && newPopupWindow.TestCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string str = newPopupWindow.TestCheckBox.Content.ToString();
            //str contains the text in the checkbox
        }

    }
```

Your `AdvancedSettingsWindow` OK button should look like this:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        Close();
    }
```

Obviously this assume that you have only one checkbox, so you'll have to expand the method a bit, but this is more efficient than using public propreties.