# How to get data from child window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application, where I have created a new window that represents a custom message box. It has two buttons - yes and no.

I am calling it from the Parent form and expect to receive the answer, which should be `"Yes"` or `"No"`, or `true` or `false`.

I am trying to do the same as `Servy`'s asnwer here: [C# - Return variable from child window to parent window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607925/c-sharp-return-variable-from-child-window-to-parent-window-in-wpf)

But for some reason, I never get the updated value, so `isAllowed` is always false.

This is the code in my Parent window:

```
bool isAllowed = false;

ChildMessageBox cmb = new ChildMessageBox();
cmb.Owner = this;
cmb.Allowed += value => isAllowed = value;
cmb.ShowDialog();

if (isAllowed) // it is always false
{
    // do something here
}
```

And then in the Child window I have:

```
public event Action<bool> Allowed;

public ChildMessageBox()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}

private void no_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Allowed(false);
     this.Close();
}

private void yes_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Allowed(true); // This is called when the Yes button is pressed
     this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your button click event handlers, you first need to set the `DialogResult` property. Like this:

```
private void no_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
    Close();
}

//Do the same for the yes button (set DialogResult to true)
...
```

This will be returned from the `ShowDialog` method, you can simply assign your `isAllowed` variable to the result of `ShowDialog`.

```
bool? isAllowed = false;
...
isAllowed = cmb.ShowDialog();

if (isAllowed == true)
{
    ...
```

Comment: So this basically means that the `Action` in the Child window is not necessary, is that right?

Comment: Worth noting that `DialogResult` is default `false`, so setting it `false` could be deemed unnecessary.